# Avoid internal patches when clipping a raster in R based on a polygon

Tags: raster, r, clip

I want to clip a raster in R based on a polygon. The analog function in arcgis that does the same is Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip.

What I have until now is:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(123)

r <- raster()
res(r) <- c( 0.016666, 0.016666 )

extent <- shapefile("colombia_2000.shp")

r <- crop(r, extent, snap='near')
r <- setValues(r, sample(x=c(0,1),size=ncell(r), replace = T))

undata_mask <- mask(r, extent)
```

You can find the "extent" file in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HLTAkqClWNzVRzWLbTvfp4Esqyc8zMRl

The polygon (extent) I am using represents the area between 1000 an 2000 meters above see level in the Andean Mountain range in Colombia, and as you can see there are some internal patches that are not covered with the polygon, which belongs to the mountain peaks that exceed this altitud range.

When I perform the crop and mask functions in R, those internal patches remain untouched as if they belonged to the polygon. When I perform the calculation in ArcGis, the internal patches are indeed clipped, which is what I want to achieve in R.

How Can I get rid of this internal patches?

Here are some images of What I just said.

The first one is with R and the second one is with ArcGIS

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should probably warn people that's an 893Mb raster, which is quite a download. Can you make a much, *much* smaller example? Like under a megabyte?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for that extra big raster. I just edit the post and add a reproducible raster instead of the former.

Answer (score 1):

First, If you want to make a reproducible example... Set resolution before than values (and don't use functions names as object name):

```r
library(raster)

set.seed(123)

r <- raster()
res(r) <- c( 0.016666, 0.016666 )
undata <- setValues(r,values = sample(x=c(0,1),
                    size=ncell(r),replace = T), extent = c( -180, 180, -90, 90))

extnt <- shapefile ("path_to/colombia_2000.shp")
crs.geo  <-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
crs(extnt) <- crs.geo
```

I've been suffering the same issue... I tried to use `rasterize()` in the past, but I got the same problem. Could be a bug o a misinterpretation of neighbours. I don't know the exact reason.

With your data:

[image]

I finally decided to take a workaround in QGIS (prior to use only open source software, also, you can make a script to program this with pyqgis).

Create a blank raster using the original one and multiplying it with raster calculator with 0.

```r
"undata@1"*0
```

After that, in the vector layer, create a new field -decimal number with at least one decimal- with a unique number to all polygons... In this case, 1.1.

[image]

Use this field to rasterize the polygon (that's the reason to use a decimal number field type):

[image]

Finally, back in R:

```r
undata_crop <- crop(undata, extnt, snap='near')
workaround <- raster("path_to/rasterized.tif")
workaround_crop <- crop(workaround, extnt, snap='near')
undata_mask <- mask(x=undata_crop,mask= workaround_crop ,maskvalue=0)
```

[image]

You can also use `undata_crop` as input to avoid to crop `workaround` (but, if `undata` is actually an input raster, is faster to work directly with it rather than cropping it in R to export to QGIS)